# AirPods won't switch to MacBook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios, bluetooth, airpods

My AirPods (1st gen) won't switch over to my MacBook Air (early 2015 running the latest Mojave) from my iPhone 8. When I click 'connect' the indicator just spins and nothing happens. Restarting resolves this, and my AirPods are then able to connect to my MacBook. Any ideas as to the cause of this? Are my AirPods perhaps faulty?

Comment: Did you try re-pairing them (button on back)? I remember I had to fudge around with my different devices initially. Try pairing them to different devices etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has always these kind of bugs with their wireless (or even wired) platforms. You just need to force it to connect.

So you can go to sound settings of system preferences and force connect there.

[image: Sound Output settings]

or if you already have the indicator in the status bar [image: Status bar icon], you can option+click on that and force connect from there.

Note that it could either fail because it may be in-use or disconnect from the other source that already connected and using it (Randomly but second option most of the times depends on what device requested new connection and what device is using it right now).

It always helps me and hope it helps you as well.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do this. One of the benefits of AirPods is seamless switching. See my comment on the question.